# I want to get request from an API URL using fetch method, but I keep on getting error 400

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to get request from an API URL using fetch method, but I keep on getting `error 400`

[image: this is the error I got from Google inspection]

This is my script

```
fetch('https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/braille/unicode.json', {
method: 'get'})
.then(response => response.json())  // convert to json
.then(json => console.log(json))    //print data to console
.catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err)); // Catch errors
```

I already test this api request using postman and it is successful, but why when I implemented in my website it is unsuccessful?

[image: this is the result i get from the postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the required `text` param in the `fetch` call causing the [API](https://api.funtranslations.com/) to return a `400` error. And you can omit `{ method: 'get' }` since it's the default.

```
const baseURL = 'https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/braille/unicode.json'
const text = 'hello'

fetch(`${baseURL}?text=${text}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: oh, I see. thank you. But how about if I don't want the text parameter to be constant? I want the text to get from user input.

Comment: @HusnaZainal You're welcome. It was just an example to give you an idea. In vanilla JS, you would do something like `const text = document.getElementById('input').value`.

Comment: oh. thank you so much. I am a newbie. that's why I need to learn more ahahha.  The error already solved. Thanks. If I want to display the response back to the front-end so that the user can see, how should I do that?

Comment: @HusnaZainal You could add an id  (for e.g. `brailleText`) to the Braille text input field and do `fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then((response) => { document.getElementById('brailleText').value = response.contents.translated.join('') })`.

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks so much. However why when i used, const text = document.getElementById('engtext').value, I get an error where it said, cannot read property 'value' of null? Is it because there is some error in my HTML coding?

Comment: @Husna Zainal Looks like there's no element with the id `engtext`. Make sure the id is correct.

Comment: yes, the id is already correct and the same.

Comment: @Husna Zainal Maybe the code runs before the DOM has loaded. Can you share a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-brook-fi3od?file=/index.html

Comment: @HusnaZainal The code in `fetchGet.js` runs before the DOM has loaded. You should set up a listener for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event and add a listener for the `submit` event on the form element to make the API request. You can check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/braille-b2w78?file=/fetchGet.js) to get an idea.

Comment: oh! it works!!! :D Thank you very much for helping me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In Postman you request the url `https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/braille/unicode.json?text=hello` and in js you request an url without any parameters.